# Extracting a section of a string in python with limitations

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string output that looks like this:

```
Distance AAAB: ,0.13634,0.13700,0.00080,0.00080,-0.00066,.00001,
Distance AAAC: ,0.12617,0.12680,0.00080,0.00080,-0.00063,,
Distance AAAD: ,0.17045,0.16990,0.00080,0.00080,0.00055,,
Distance AAAE: ,0.09330,0.09320,0.00080,0.00080,0.00010,,
Distance AAAF: ,0.21048,0.21100,0.00080,0.00080,-0.00052,,
Distance AAAG: ,0.02518,0.02540,0.00040,0.00040,-0.00022,,
Distance AAAH: ,0.11404,0.11450,0.00120,0.00110,-0.00046,,
Distance AAAI: ,0.10811,0.10860,0.00080,0.00070,-0.00049,,
Distance AAAJ: ,0.02430,0.02400,0.00200,0.00200,0.00030,,
Distance AAAK: ,0.09449,0.09400,0.00200,0.00100,0.00049,,
Distance AAAL: ,0.07689,0.07660,0.00050,0.00050,0.00029,
```

What I want to do is extract a specific set of data out of this block, for example only Distance AAAH like so:

```
Distance AAAH: ,0.11404,0.11450,0.00120,0.00110,-0.00046,,
```

The measurements will always begin with Distance AAA*: with the star being the only character that will change.

Complications:
This needs to be generic, because I have a lot of different data sets and so Distance AAAH might not always be followed by Distance AAAI or preceded by Distance AAAG, since the measurements for different items vary. I also can't rely on .len(), because the last measurement can sometimes be blank (As it is with Distance AAAH) or can be filled (As with Distance AAAB. And I don't think I can use .find(), because I need all of the numbers following Distance AAAH.

I am still very new and I tried my best to find a solution similar to this problem, but have not had much luck.

Comment: Could you provide some more examples of the type of query you will be doing?  For example, are you always going to provide the full sequence of letters?  Will you use wild-cards, such as A*L?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search your text by this script :

```
#fullText = YOUR STRING
text = fullText.splitlines()
for line in text:
    if line.startswith('Distance AAAH:'):
        print line
```

Output:`Distance AAAH: ,0.11404,0.11450,0.00120,0.00110,-0.00046,,`

Comment: That's a really terrible condition, unless you can make clear guarantees that the data on the line won't contain `AAAH`. `if line.startswith('Distance AAAH:'):` would be a lot safer and clearly indicates your intent.

Comment: Instead of `split('\n')`, you can use `splitlines()`. Also, `str` is a terrible variable name, as it shadows the type.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Right, edited.
But i think good to know for peoples ; use

**`if "AAAH" in line:`**
when need search in whole line

Answer (score 1):

You could use `re` module. And making a function should be convenient.

```
import re
def SearchDistance(pattern,text):
    pattern = pattern.replace(' ','\s')
    print re.findall(r'{0}.+'.format(pattern),a)

SearchDistance('Distance AAAH',a)
```

Output:

```
['Distance AAAH: ,0.11404,0.11450,0.00120,0.00110,-0.00046,,']
```

Comment: You probably want to use [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) on the pattern you receive, unless you're intending to allow regex specials to be passed and used by the caller. Obviously not an issue if the patterns never contain regex special characters, but that's a bad assumption to make most of the time.